# VIM buffer for MySQL CLI interpreter?

Tags: bash, vim, mysql

I just learned that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> in the Bash CLI will open the current command in a VIM buffer for editing. That is nice, but where I really need this feature is the MySQL CLI interpreter, and that keyboard shortcut does not work there. I am aware of the inherent readline VIM feature, but I find it more annoying then useful. Is there any way to open the current MySQL command in a VIM buffer just as is possible with a Bash command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edit`, or `\e`.

This could be found by running `$ man commandname`.

Comment: Thank you Romaini. I did search google, but I did not read the mysql manpage yet. I will go over that, and some other manpages that I have been meaning to review. Thank you!

Comment: I should note for future readers that this method is extremely limited. Only the last command can be edited, and the finished command is not shown in the MySQL CLI.